# QR decomposition of finitely generated matrix groups

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Given a finite (or more generally, compact) set of matrices $\{A_i\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, we can generate a subgroup $G$ of $GL(\mathbb{R},n)$. Now, since every matrix has a QR decomposition, we can write $g = q \cdot r$ for all $g\in G$, where $q$ is an orthogonal matrix and $r$ is upper-triangular. Since both orthogonal and upper-triangular matrices form groups, we can write $G=O T$ as a Zappa-Szep product (according to wikipedia) of $O$ (a subgroup of the orthogonal group) and $T$ (a subgroup containing triangular matrices, perhaps not necessarily only consisting of upper-triangular matrices).

My questions are:

1) Is the reason it's a Zappa-Szep product and not a semi-direct product due to the fact that $T$ is not normal? Is it possible to find a normal group that contains $T$ and allows for $g = q \cdot r$?

2) Is there anything we can say about the relationship of the subgroups $O$ and $T$? Are there perchance any situations in which $q^{-1} r q \in T$ for $q\in O$ and $r \in T$?

Comment: 0) It doesn't work, because if you decompose an element $g\in G$ as $g_qg_r$ with $(g_q,g_r)\in Q\times R$, you have no guarantee that $g_q\in G$. So Your claim that $G=OT$ does not work. 1) No: the normal subgroups of $GL(n,R)$ are pretty rare (they are central or contain $SL(n,R)$). 2) is senseless because of 0.

Comment: Of course! I failed to consider your point 0). Because I have control of the group being generated in my case, what about if I generated a group from the set $\{A_i, q_i, r_i\,:\, A_i = q_i \cdot r_i\}$? This way I would know that  $q_i$, $r_i \in G := <\{A_i, q_i, r_i\,:\, A_i = q_i \cdot r_i\}>$. In this case, I don't see R being central, since it contains upper-triangular elements, though. 

To some extent, I'm hoping for an analog for the Levi decomposition for finitely generated groups.